# unwanted indent after line wrap

Tags: apache-fop, docx4j

I'm converting some worddocuments (docx) with docx4j 6.1.2 and docx4j-export-fo 8.1.2 (apache FOP 2.3) to PDF with Java 11 like this:

```
// Load File
var wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(wordDocument.getInputStream());

// Convert to PDF
var out = new FastByteArrayOutputStream();
Docx4J.toPDF(wordMLPackage, out);
return new ByteArrayResource(out.toByteArray());
```

In all paragraphs in the generated PDF there is a formatting issue I can't get a grip on. The following image shows a section from the docx in word.

[image]

The next image shows the section from the pdf file.

1. Each wrapped line starts with some extra indent on the left side.
2. Long lines are not wrapped.

[image]

Any ideas?

Edit 1:

The docx File is here: https://filebin.net/cux9s1p5ufm1vgul.

Comment: Post your docx somewhere?

Comment: @JasonPlutext see this file https://filebin.net/cux9s1p5ufm1vgul - anyway I tried it with different files always leading to the same result

Comment: Hi Kai that filebin has expired.  Would you mind posting it again? thanks

Comment: @JasonPlutext: I didn't keep a copy of the file, but I remember it's been a blank word document with a lorem ipsum content paragraph. No formatting or whatsoever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>docx4j-export-fo</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

works ok.

It seems the problem is white-space-collapse="false" white-space-treatment="preserve" introduced by https://github.com/plutext/docx4j-export-FO/commit/4451111aa02a698ed54788299513f7eac74bd996#diff-eeb9c00a64479f4ff29769e29a6a0cd7R455